# MFC: Not getting WM_CHAR in CDialogEx dialog?

Tags: winapi, mfc, windows-messages

I have a dialog with no controls derived from `CDialogEx`.  I receive `OnKeyDown()` messages but never receive a `OnChar()` ?   I even tried overriding `PreTranslateMessage()` and just returning 0 when receiving a `WM_KEYDOWN` message as a test, still no `OnChar()`?   What am I missing so I don't have to use `ToUnicode()` or `ToAscii()` in  the `OnKeyDown()` routine?

TIA!

Comment: So if I wanted to take action on a + or - key press (either upper row or numeric keypad), do you have a sample?

Comment: Without a control can receive keyboard focus in dialog box it seems can't receive key message/command (except `Enter` key). You may need create a custom dialog box. Please check [Creating Your Dialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/creating-your-dialog-class?view=vs-2019) to see if it helps.